# How to reduce the volume of the GTN750 traffic warning beep?

Tags: flight-instruments, gnss, transponder

We've got a GTN 750 with ADS-B IN and OUT. When we encounter traffic it emits a high pitched pulsing beep. It cannot be muted by any means - say you are on final and there's an aircraft holding short but with an active transponder, it will beep like mad which is really distracting.

Is there a way to at least adjust the volume?

At half the volume it presently is at it would be bearable. We couldn't find any setting to effect that.

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer? That seems to be a likely place to start.

Comment: Yes. It's really hard to get a useful reply from Garmin.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous alert volume settings in the configuration pages of the GTN 750. Your local Garmin authorised dealer/installer should be able to identify the correct setting for the particular traffic system installed in your airplane.